# How to name a DataTriggered UserControl so that it will be visible?

Tags: wpf

I have the following in a layout:

```
<ContentControl>
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentPane}" Value="Pane1">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <uc:UserControl x:Name="?????" />
```

In plain words, the `UserControl` is loaded into the `Template` based on a `DataTrigger`. It all works wonderfully, except for one thing: no matter how I want to name this `UserControl` so that it will appear in the main layout, it doesn't appear. I need to get a reference to the control so that I can attach event handlers to it.

If there is an alternative idea of how to reach the `UserControl` from the main layout without naming it specifically, that would be a solution, too.

Comment: why dont you directly set eventhandlers in xaml?

Comment: If you mean EventSetters, they make the app crash when the main page is loaded, I couldn't yet trace the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name the `ContentControl` and get the `ControlTemplate` from the `Template` property and then you can use the `FindName` method on it to get access to your `UserControl`:

```
<ContentControl Name="YourContentControl">
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentPane}" Value="Pane1">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <uc:UserControl x:Name="YourUserControl" />
```

Then in code:

```
ControlTemplate yourTemplate = YourContentControl.Template;
UserControl yourUserControl = 
    (UserControl)yourTemplate.FindName("YourUserControl", YourContentControl);
if (yourUserControl != null)
{
    // do something with your control here
}
```

Of course, if you use this code when the `UserControl` has not yet been set as the `Template`, then you will get an error. Therefore, you should check for `null`:

Comment: Very promising, thanks. Yes, exactly, what I get now is `null` but I'll look into it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I see it that way : what you are doing when defining the `Template` property is defining the `class` to instantiate when wpf is templating the `control`. The `uc:UserControl` is not a reference to an instance, therefore you can not refer to it using the `x:Name` attribute.

Maybe it's easier to see that its not an instance if you had defined you `ControlTemplate` in a separate resource :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
  <uc:UserControl x:Name="MyUC">
</ControlTemplate>

<ContentControl x:Name="MyFirstContentControl">
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentPane}" Value="Pane1">
          <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}">
 [...]

<ContentControl x:Name="MySecondContentControl">
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentPane}" Value="Pane1">
          <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}">

[...]
```

Now, if you refer to "MyUC", which one of the two instances would it refere to ? The `UserControl` inside `MyFirstContentControl`'s template or the one inside `MySecondContentControl` ? That's why you have to dynamicaly look for something like (psoeudo code) MyFirstControl.MyUC, as Sheridan explained.